# Nautilus won't use Gnome 3 color scheme?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes

I'm using ubuntu 12.10 gnome remix, and I've managed to change the color scheme for most of the default adwaita theme, but when I open up nautilus and click on a folder/file, or select something on the desktop, it shows this "default blue" color that reminds me of windows, and that clashes just a bit with my current color scheme and desktop background.

Is there any way I can change just the colors that nautilus uses, or force it to use the theme's selection colors?

Comment: Screenshot available?

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus should be controlled by the GTK+ theme, whereas Gnome Shell uses its own theme. You'll need to change the GTK+ theme to something that looks better with your Gnome Shell theme.

The easiest way is to pick up Gnome Tweak Tool and change the theme (I think there's an "Adwaita" GTK+ theme to go with the Shell theme). If that doesn't give you enough control, then you can probably find a GTK+ theme switcher that will give you the control you're looking for.

Comment: I did change the GTK+ theme, and edited it's theme colors directly. Nautilus still doesn't use the theme colors, and I'm completely baffled as to why.

Comment: Hmm...that sounds like it might be a bug. Have you tried looking in the bug tracker (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ for Nautilus and Ubuntu, https://launchpad.net/ugr for Gnome Remix)? If there's not a bug already there, it might be worth filing one.